# Dependency Injection - Unity Constructor injection not working, only getter setter injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service, dependency-injection, repository, unity-container

I am having issues with Unity Dependency Injection. When I try to use constructor injection, my injected services stay empty/null.

```
public UserService(IUnitOfWorkIntranet unitOfWork, IUserRepository userRepository)
   {
     mappingToDomainModel = IntranetMappingToDomainModel.GetMappingToDomainModelInstance;
     IntranetAutoMapperConfiguration autoMapper = IntranetAutoMapperConfiguration.GetAutoMapperConfigurationInstance;
     unitOfWorkIntranet = unitOfWork;
     userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

However, when I use a getter everything works just fine.

```
private IUserRepository _userRepository
   {
      get
   {
      return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUserRepository)) as UserRepository;
   }
   }
```

As far as I know it is configured properly in UnityConfig.cs

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkIntranet, UnitOfWorkIntranet>();
container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

Am I missing something here? Why is my constructor injection broken?

Any help is welcome, Regards!

Comment: How does the `UserService` resolved?

Comment: @Sergey Shushlyapin Thanks for your response! It gets resolved using getter setter Dependency Injection (with Unity) in a controller.

Comment: You _could_ do that but that is rather a workaround since property injection is considered as optional. I suppose that the `IUserRepository` is a _must-have_ dependency for the `UserService`, so it should be injected via constructor to make this relation clear.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is constructor injection is not working. The object simply stays empty.

Comment: What does 'empty' mean? Show the fill `UserService` code.

Comment: By that I mean the object is null. I was expecting Unity to fill it. Thanks for your responses and the code example. I'll try them now and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple *working* example of the constructor injection using Unity:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkIntranet { }

public class UnitOfWorkIntranet : IUnitOfWorkIntranet{}

public interface IUserRepository { }

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository{}

public interface IUserService{}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public IUnitOfWorkIntranet UnitOfWork { get; }
    public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; }
    public UserService(IUnitOfWorkIntranet unitOfWork, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

Configuration and resolving:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkIntranet, UnitOfWorkIntranet>();
container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

var service = (UserService)container.Resolve<IUserService>();
```

Comment: This is about what our code looks like right now. I added public IUnitOfWorkIntranet UnitOfWork { get; }  public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; } but this didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is there a default constructor in your `UserService` class? I suspect the [Unity Dependency Resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection) might not be configured properly.

Comment: I don't think so, the only constructor in the UserService class is listed in the post above. Again thanks for all your effort so far!